# Display streaming output from bash magic in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use bash magic in my iPython notebook for bash commands that print intermediate log out. I have noticed that the output of the bash program is only displayed in the output cell at the end of execution. Is there a way to change this behavior and have the output be displayed as it streams out of the bash program?

Comment: Also very curious. Given that the functionality as complex as interacting with web apps is provided out-of-the-box by [IPython.display.IFrame](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html), it seems like this should be a relatively simple addition